# R - renaming all column values at once

Tags: r

I have a column of chars ranging from '0' to '11'.

I want them to be 1 number higher, so I did this:

```
  myDf$id[myDf$id == "0"] <- "1"
  myDf$id[myDf$id == "1"] <- "2"
  myDf$id[myDf$id == "2"] <- "3"
  myDf$id[myDf$id == "3"] <- "4"
  myDf$id[myDf$id == "4"] <- "5"
  myDf$id[myDf$id == "5"] <- "6"
  myDf$id[myDf$id == "6"] <- "7"
  myDf$id[myDf$id == "7"] <- "8"
  myDf$id[myDf$id == "8"] <- "9"
  myDf$id[myDf$id == "9"] <- "10"
  myDf$id[myDf$id == "10"] <- "11"
  myDf$id[myDf$id == "11"] <- "12
```

But obviously all that does is to rename everything to '12'

Is there a way of doing this all at once so everything is not just made '12'?

Many thanks

Comment: `as.character(as.numeric(myDf$id)+1)` might be worth a try

Comment: If you would have done your code from 11 to 1 you would have gotten your result as well. But @missuse solution is a lot faster than typing all the different options.

Comment: Thank you guys. Working perfectly :)